# How to monitor mysql percentage disk utilization?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql world and not sure if there is a way to calculate mysql TableSpace/DiskSpace utilization in percentage. I am aware mysql does not provide upper limit or free space like Oracle DB, but just space consumed by Index tables and Data Tables. I have decided to add these two values and divide with total space available for mountpoint mentioned in "datadir" attribute of mysql. My queries are :

1. Is this right way of doing this ??
2. What if databases/tables are created on different mountpoints. Is there a way to monitor available space for mysql instance then ?

Comment: you monitor though the OS and the file-systems not through MySQL

Comment: Thanks HBruijn...I tried that approach itself. But what if tables are created on multiple mountpoints, will "datadir" show multiple entries ?? If not , what should be my approach in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can start here: https://github.com/banyek/Utilities/tree/master/monitor_space

This will give you the actual table sizes, so you only have to know how big they are. If you know the free space you have you can add the missing functionality here :)

Comment: Thanks Banyek. I understand these perl scripts gives me the current utilization and delta change in sizes of tables. But what approach I should use to get percentage consumption by my mysql instance. Also, what approach should be used if tables are created over multiple mountpoints ?

Comment: You can revert this. I mean, I've shared you this stuff to give you ideas (what to query, etc.) all the others will depend on you. :) And if you put that to github, I'll be very happy :)